# remove every line with criteria except for this different criteria

Tags: bash, awk, grep

this is the file

```
  $ cat temp
AG,17.060816,-61.796428,Antigua and Barbuda,1
AI,18.220554,-63.068615,Anguilla,1
AS,-14.270972,-170.132217,American Samoa,1
BB,13.193887,-59.543198,Barbados,1
BM,32.321384,-64.75737,Bermuda,1
BS,25.03428,-77.39628,Bahamas,1
CA,56.130366,-106.346771,Canada,1
DM,15.414999,-61.370976,Dominica,1
DO,18.735693,-70.162651,Dominican Republic,1
GD,12.262776,-61.604171,Grenada,1
GU,13.444304,144.793731,Guam,1
JM,18.109581,-77.297508,Jamaica,1
KN,17.357822,-62.782998,Saint Kitts and Nevis,1
KY,19.513469,-80.566956,Cayman Islands,1
LC,13.909444,-60.978893,Saint Lucia,1
MP,17.33083,145.38469,Northern Mariana Islands,1
MS,16.742498,-62.187366,Montserrat,1
PR,18.220833,-66.590149,Puerto Rico,1
TC,21.694025,-71.797928,Turks and Caicos Islands,1
TT,10.691803,-61.222503,Trinidad and Tobago,1
US,37.09024,-95.712891,United States,1
VC,12.984305,-61.287228,Saint Vincent and the Grenadines,1
AD,42.546245,1.601554,Andorra,376
AE,23.424076,53.847818,United Arab Emirates,971
AF,33.93911,67.709953,Afghanistan,93
AL,41.153332,20.168331,Albania,355
AM,40.069099,45.038189,Armenia,374
AN,12.226079,-69.060087,Netherlands Antilles,599
AO,-11.202692,17.873887,Angola,244
```

this removes every row/line that ends with `,1`.

```
$ cat temp | grep -vE ',1$'
```

How do I remove every row/line that ends with `,1` except for the United States?

So my outpit would look like

```
AD,42.546245,1.601554,Andorra,376
AE,23.424076,53.847818,United Arab Emirates,971
AF,33.93911,67.709953,Afghanistan,93
AL,41.153332,20.168331,Albania,355
AM,40.069099,45.038189,Armenia,374
AN,12.226079,-69.060087,Netherlands Antilles,599
AO,-11.202692,17.873887,Angola,244
US,37.09024,-95.712891,United States,1             <<<<<<---US remains
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk to the rescue

```
awk -F, '$NF!=1 || $(NF-1)=="United States"'
```

Or, using first field

```
awk -F, '$1=="US" || $NF!=1'
```

Or, equivalently

```
awk -F, '!($1!="US" && $NF==1)'
```

You should think of what records will be printed, because that's what the script will do.

Comment: The thing is "remove lines ending with ,1 except for the US", so I would better rethink it as `$5!=1 && $4!="US"`. The current solution is a bit confusing.

Comment: Since the OP said `every row/line that ends with ,1` consider using $NF and $(NF-1) instead of hard-coding $5 and $4. may not matter tho...

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`:

```
$ cat temp | grep -E ',(United States,1|[^1,]|[^,]{2,})$'
US,37.09024,-95.712891,United States,1
AD,42.546245,1.601554,Andorra,376
AE,23.424076,53.847818,United Arab Emirates,971
AF,33.93911,67.709953,Afghanistan,93
AL,41.153332,20.168331,Albania,355
AM,40.069099,45.038189,Armenia,374
AN,12.226079,-69.060087,Netherlands Antilles,599
AO,-11.202692,17.873887,Angola,244
```

Or, better yet, eliminate the `cat`:

```
grep -E ',(United States,1|[^1,]|[^,]{2,})$' temp
```

#### How it works

We have eliminated `-v` and reversed the logic.  We print any line that matches `,United States,1$` or that matches `,[^1,]$` or that matches `,[^,]{2,}$`.